# How to take input in the same line in Python?

Tags: python

i need the user to add input in same line. i wantthe use to input without giving gaps?

```
x,y,z=input("Enter number").split()
x=float(x)
z=float(z)
if y=="+":
    value=x+z
elif y=="-":
    value=x-z
elif y=="*":
    value=x*z
elif y=="/":
    value=x/z


print(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do this would be with the eval() function.
E.g.

```
x = input()
print(eval(x))
```

The eval() function takes in a string, and returns its value.

For example,

```
eval("10/2") = 5
```

The input() function returns input as a string, so you can just plug that into eval().

Comment: I want to take 3 input at the same time without giving any space in the input.

Comment: the method given above works very well for what you're going for

Comment: I am new to it so i may not have understood it. can you please elaborate or tell me where to put that code.

Comment: i tried it but it does not work for big numbers.

Comment: can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the eval() function here.

```
print(eval(input()))
```

This should work

Comment: I want to take 3 input at the same time without giving any space in the input.

Comment: Why do you want to take 3 inputs here? You don't need to. Did you try this out? All it needs is an input expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
x,y,z=input("Enter number").strip()
x=float(x)
z=float(z)
if y=="+":
    value=x+z
elif y=="-":
    value=x-z
elif y=="*":
    value=x*z
elif y=="/":
    value=x/z


print(value)
```

You can try this for bigger numbers:

```
        import re
        x,y,z=re.split(r'(\D)', input("Enter number")) 
        x=float(x)
        z=float(z)
        if y=="+":
            value=x+z
        elif y=="-":
            value=x-z
        elif y=="*":
            value=x*z
        elif y=="/":
            value=x/z
        
        
        print(value)
```

Comment: @samarpandhungana look above the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

eval evaluates the string that it is given, so calling eval("3+4") without any spaces will give 7.

Comment: could you please provide an example where it does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Using eval is rather unsafe as it allows the user to do any operation. You could use regular expression to capture the numbers and the operator:

```
import re
input_str = '123*456'
num1 = re.search('^[1-9]*', input_str).group(0)
num2 = re.search('[1-9]*$', input_str).group(0)
op = re.search('(\+|\-|\*|/)', input_str).group(0)

print(num1, num2, op)
# 123 456 *
```

Then you can call the function you have:

```
x=float(num1)
z=float(num2)
y=op
if y=="+":
    value=x+z
elif y=="-":
    value=x-z
elif y=="*":
    value=x*z
elif y=="/":
    value=x/z


print(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `re.split()` to split the input based on the given operations:

```
import re
inp = '3+4'
inp = re.split('([+\-*/])', inp) # split the input based on the operation
x, z = float(inp[0]), float(inp[2])
y = inp[1]
if y=="+":
    value=x+z
elif y=="-":
    value=x-z
elif y=="*":
    value=x*z
elif y=="/":
    value=x/z

print(value)
```